# How to open new Instances of Opera (New Window/ Speed Dial) in Linux- Workspaces?

Tags: linux, browser, opera, fedora

I'm using Fedora and I've just now downloaded Opera, its awesome . But I've got one problem and that is when I switch to New Workspace and open Opera (new Instance), it will not be opened in present Workspace but opens up Speed Dial tab in the previous Workspace next to current browsing tab and this is creating problem while browsing, I need to move the Current browsing session windows to next Workspace or stay in only one.

My `About Opera` revealed the following information:

```
About Opera
Version information
Version
12.16 
Build
1860 
Platform
Linux 
System
i686, 2.6.32.26-175.fc12.i686.PAE 
Browser identification 
Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16
```

So how can I open Multiple instances of Opera in New Workspaces? Let me know, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You left unclear, which window manager/desktop environment you are using.

Assuming you use Gnome, you can do the following:

Navigate to `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/`, do a `grep -r opera *`, which should output something like this:

```
about/%gconf.xml:       <stringvalue>opera -newpage %s</stringvalue>
http/%gconf.xml:        <stringvalue>opera -newpage %s</stringvalue>
https/%gconf.xml:       <stringvalue>opera -newpage %s</stringvalue>
unknown/%gconf.xml:     <stringvalue>opera -newpage %s</stringvalue>
```

Open these files with your favourite editor and change all those `-newpage` (or whatever value your files show as options) to `-newwindow`. Keep in mind, that now **every** link you open from **outside** Opera will open in a **new** window/instance, only links opened from **within** Opera will open in the **same** window.

I guess this is not quite the answer you were looking for, but as far as I know, there is no (convenient) way you can probe for an already running instance of a window on the same desktop to differentiate this behaviour.

Comment: neither -newpage nor -newwindow work with 33.0.1990.43 (also tried double dash)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the startup file opera.desktop in /usr/share/applications. Change "Exec=opera" to "Exec=opera --new-window".